# Como gerar numero sem repetição com um botão de pause?

Tags: javascript

Gostaria que tivesse um botão com a função de `PAUSE`, e que eliminasse números duplicados.

Um contador embaixo que quando eu aperto o `PAUSE` ele exibi o numero do resultado com o TOTAL de linhas geradas .

```js
function append(el) {
    //eu coloco os 16 primeiro digitos aqui, e ele gera mais 4 aleatorio
    var txt = "1212" + "9057" + "9240" + "8105";
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9000) + 1000);
    document.getElementById(el).innerHTML += txt + x + "<br>";
    //tempo de gerar numeros 1s
    setTimeout(function() {
        append("timeout");
    }, 1000);
    //AQUI EU QUERO UM FILTRA PARA NAO DUPLICAR
    // E UM BOTAO DE PAUSE E UM TXT COM TOTAL DE LINHAS GERADAS

}


append("timeout");
```

```html
<p>GERADOR DE NUMEROS SEM REPETIÇAO E COM BOTAO DE PAUSE</p>
<hr>
<button name="pause" id="pause">PAUSE</button>
<div id="timeout"></div>
<div id="interval"></div>
```

Comment: Entendi, que você quer pausar o gerador de número assim que você clicar no botão pause, correto?

Comment: SIM , pausar ele quando eu quiser, e no final do pause ou do resultado ele me apresentar o total de números gerados('Resultados total gerados --> 5040 ') *[EXEMPLO]* no final de cada pause ele me apresenta o total, e se tiver como acrescenta para não duplicar tbm seria ótimo, mas meu foco esta mais em ter um botão de PAUSE e um contador total de resultados a ser exibido no fim

Comment: Eu vou adicionar uma resposta, e vou editando pra ajustar a sua necessidade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) Retorna um ID de intervalo, e pode ser passando como parâmetro na função `clearInterval()`, caso queira parar sua execução.

## Veja funcionando:

```js
var stop;
var contador = 0;
function append(el) {
    contador++;
    var txt = "1212" + "9057" + "9240" + "8105";
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9000) + 1000);
    document.getElementById(el).innerHTML += txt + x + "<br>";

    stop = setTimeout(function() {
        append("timeout");
    }, 1000);


}
function pause(){
   document.getElementById('totalItens').innerHTML = 'Total de Itens:' + contador;
   clearInterval(stop);
}
append("timeout");
```

```html
<p>GERADOR DE NUMEROS SEM REPETIÇAO E COM BOTAO DE PAUSE</p>
<hr>
<button name="pause" id="pause" onclick='pause()'>PAUSE</button>
<div id="timeout"></div>
<div id="interval"></div>
<div id="totalItens"></div>
```

Comment: muito bom, era isso mesmo, se eu quiser colocar um contador eu devo abrir outra pergunta ? e Aceitar essa ? ou prossigo aqui mesmo...

Comment: @MandrakeVenom Adicionei o total de itens que foram gerados.

Comment: OK, ja aceitei a resposta, valew cara ja deu pra mim entender mais sobre javascript e as funções de Interval, timeout e clear, vlw pelas resposta rápida

Comment: @MandrakeVenom bom que pude ajudar :). Recomendo a leitura no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender um pouco mais sobre o site.

Answer (score 1):

O que eu faria é o seguinte:

Primeiro usar setInterval em vez de setTimeout:

```
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ gerarNumero() }, 1000);
```

Quando quiser parar, use clearInterval:

```
clearInterval(myVar);
```

Já o caso das duplicações é mais difícil, recomendo fazer um array e colocar cada número gerado nele, e então verificar se o novo número está no array, se não estiver, retorne o número, se estiver rode a função novamente...

```
var numeros = [];

function gerarNumero(){    
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9000) + 1000);
    var existe = false;
    for(var i in numeros){
        if(numeros[i] == x) existe = true;
        break;
    }    
    if(!existe){
        numeros.push(x);
        document.getElementById(el).innerHTML += txt + x + "<br>";
    }else{
        gerarNumero();
    }
}
```

Não testei o código, mas será algo nessa linha...

Espero que ajude...

Comment: Só lembrando que em algum momento esse código vai rodar infinitamente pois não existirá mais nenhum número inédito e ele ficara chamando ele mesmo pra sempre... precisa tratar esse caso...

Comment: E eu quero um contador de resultado final, quando eu clicar no PAUSE(ou quando ele termina todas as combinações), ele vai da um break; e envia um innerHTML falando pra mim "Resultado total de linhas ->" dai aparece a contagem de quantos resultados diferente deu( sem duplicados ),no caso ele vai gerar o resultado final de 4 digitos combinados diferente (0-9) eh basicamente isso que eu desejo realizar, Obrigado msm assim pela atencao

Comment: por exemplo 4 digitos gerados sao , 5040 combinações, quero que no final dele realizar todas, ele me enviei um innerHTML escrito "RESULTADO TOTAL GERADOS--> 5040 " por isso meu interesse no contador tambem... se eu quiser pausa o resultado, ele me mostra o total gerado, acho que agora consegui expressa minha ideia ^^